# how can i check if an array of objects contains a key which is in array of strings js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

We have an array of objects like

```
const arr = [{id: "someId", name: {...}}, ...];
const skippedKeys = ["id"...]
```

How can i filtered the array of object based on skipped keys?
The result should be:

```
const result = [{name: {...}}, ...];
```

Also i don't want to make a cycle inside the cycle.
the result also could be implemented using lodash library.
we should remove key with value as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const result = arr.map(obj =>
  Object.keys(obj).reduce(
    (res, key) => (
      skippedKeys.includes(key) ? res : {...res, [key]: obj[key]}
    ),
    {},
));
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. but we should remove key with value as well. i will add this to the description also

Answer (score 3):

Since you stated that it could be implemented using lodash, here is some code using lodash:

```js
let result = _.map(arr, (el)=> _.omit(el, skippedKeys))
```

Answer (score 2):

It's simple and no need for any nested cycles. There are two option to do that

1. Using `includes` function

```
    const result = arr.filter((item) => !result.includes(item.id));
```

2. Using `set`

```
    const dataSet = new Set(skippedKeys);
    const result = arr.filter((item) => !dataSet.has(item.id));
```

I prefer the second one as it excludes double checks. Hope the answer was helpful.